# Uninstall specific version of mysql OSX

Tags: macos, mysql, uninstall, osx-yosemite

I installed mysql using .dmg, and then I realized I already have mysql installed. Now I have two versions, and I would like to keep the one that was shipped with OSX.

Is there a way to do it and how?

Answer (score 0):

First take a backup of existing database using mysqldump and stop  mysql server. then follow these

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
edit /etc/hostconfig and remove the line MYSQLCOM=-YES-
rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*

sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.*
```

Comment: but that will unistall both mysql versions, right?

Comment: Did you configured a different 'port' for the 2nd installation, because two programs cannot listen on the same port at the same time